# uWSGI: running separate instances for each domain?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

basically I am following the guide from

https://gist.github.com/mplewis/6076082

and I am wondering what is the implication of running 3 domains on 3 separate uWSGI instances on the same server? Should I be using emperor mode instead? I gave that up because it was quite complicated to setup and it was taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using Emperor is the cleanest way but not the only one.

I personally suggest to use it.

Setup is straight-forward. Just as nginx, you'll have an `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available` and `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled' symlink structure. Configuration of each domain is few lines. Look at some example configurations online.